# how to use recordset movelast

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ado.net

i need help for the code that i can use old rs.movelast to vb.net 2010..
any simple way to query my record that automatic select the last..

here is my connection sample i just call it only in any form..///

```
Public Function ExecuteSQLQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim sqlCon As New OleDbConnection(CnString)
        Dim sqlDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery, sqlCon)
        Dim sqlCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
        sqlDT.Reset() ' refresh 
        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return sqlDT
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlDT.rows(sqlDT.rows.count-1) will be the last record of your DataTable sqlDT. sqlDT.rows.count-1 will return you the last index of the rows in the filled table. Hope it will help you. Thanks

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Public CnString As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Password=sa;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Accounts"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ssql As String = "Select * from TBL_Access"
    Dim dt As DataTable

    dt = ExecuteSQLQuery(ssql)
    TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0) 'Value of First Column of Last Row of DataTable dt
    TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(1) 'Value of Second Column of Last Row of DataTable dt
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteSQLQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String) As DataTable
    Try

        Dim sqlCon As New OleDbConnection(CnString)
        Dim sqlDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery, sqlCon)
        Dim sqlCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(sqlDA)
        Dim sqlDT As New DataTable
        sqlDT.Reset() ' refresh  
        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
        Return sqlDT
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error : " & ex.Message)
        Return Nothing

    End Try
End Function



End Class
```

Comment: sir.. can u do it in complete code.. i try sqlDT.rows(sqlDT.rows.count-1) but i got an error.. thank you for the reply..

Comment: Please check my edited reply. Complete working code is in there. Thanks